# How to parse a json from URL?

Tags: json, android-emulator

I have a `JSON` URL I need to parse, How can we do that?

Comment: Examples of what you want to achieve and what you have would be helpful for us.

Comment: Some info on the language you're working in might help too.

Answer (score 0):

all the info you need on how to parse json is described here:

http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

For an object:

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json_string);

For an array:

JSONArray json = new JSONArray(json_string);